# pysnmp-lextudio using next() with the getCmd() generator leads to TypeError: 'tuple' object is not an iterator

Tags: python, typeerror, generator, snmp, pysnmp

I have removed pysnmp and installed pysnmp-lextudio in an attempt to bring my codebase up to python 3.12.2

Code that ran with previous pysnmp versions now returns the error:
'tuple' object is not an iterator

Offending code is next() of last line:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
g = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
    CommunityData('community', mpModel=1),
    UdpTransportTarget((ipAddress, port)),
    ContextData(),
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)))
        
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
```

Any insight is welcome, device behaving via snmp walk.

Comment: You should go through the upgrade guide if possible, https://docs.lextudio.com/pysnmp/upgrade#sync-api-based-on-asyncio as we expect tons of issues when you move from 4.x to 6.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because whereas the library `pynsmp` seems to return a *generator* from the `getCmd` function (see [documentation](https://pysnmp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/hlapi/v3arch/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/getcmd.html#pysnmp.hlapi.getCmd), the `pysnmp-lexstudio` already [performs the query](https://docs.lextudio.com/pysnmp/docs/hlapi/asyncio/sync/manager/cmdgen/getcmd#get-command).

The example from `pynsmp-lextudio` site:

```
>>> from pysnmp.hlapi import *
>>> g = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
...            CommunityData('public'),
...            UdpTransportTarget(('demo.pysnmp.com', 161)),
...            ContextData(),
...            ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)))
>>> g
(None, 0, 0, [ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(ObjectName('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0')), DisplayString('SunOS zeus.pysnmp.com 4.1.3_U1 1 sun4m'))])
```

And from the `pysnmp` documentation:

```
>>> from pysnmp.hlapi import *
>>> g = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
...            CommunityData('public'),
...            UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
...            ContextData(),
...            ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)))
>>> next(g)
(None, 0, 0, [ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(ObjectName('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0')), DisplayString('SunOS zeus.snmplabs.com 4.1.3_U1 1 sun4m'))])
```

Why this has changed, I don't know, but notice the missing `next()` on the first example.

In fact, if you do just this:

```
>>> print(getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
... CommunityData('community', mpModel=1),
... UdpTransportTarget((ipAddress, port)),
... ContextData(),
... ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0))))
(RequestTimedOut('No SNMP response received before timeout'), 0, 0, [])
```

You notice that the command is immediately called without `next`.

So tl;dr: in your old version, `g` is a generator, in the new one it's a response.

Comment: In general, the difference on method signatures was caused by Ilya himself, that asyncio and asyncore based methods look differently. We preferred the asyncio version and decided to stick with that in all possible ways.

Comment: Thank you Teemu & Lex, I should have rtfd first, and have since poured over the pysnmp 6.0 docs on your site. Excellent documentation by the way, I really appreciate the work you've put into this Lex. Cheers.